# Web page display in IE9 and earlier

Tags: html, css

i made web page and styled it using CSS3 (gradients, image-border, text-shadow etc.). Our work browser (IE9) totally ruined the look of it. Don't you please know how to fix in css that when browser is lower than IE10, don't use this set of styles but this set of style? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you must know how to fix it yourself, no one can do it here for free, since it might take hours or days..who knows. I suggest you should hire an expert in CSS. For the other part of the question see - http://browserhacks.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are differents solutions.

## 1 IE Conditional Comments in the "head"

ex:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
/* css for IE 8 */
</style>
<![endif]-->

 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

## 2 CSS Rules Specific to Explorer (IE CSS hacks)

IE8 or below: to write CSS rules specificially to IE8 or below, add a backslash and 9 (\9) at the end before the semicolon.
IE7 or below: add an asterisk (*) before the CSS property.
IE6: add an underscore (_) before the property.

ex:

```
.box {

background: gray; /* standard */

background: pink\9; /* IE 8 and below */

*background: green; /* IE 7 and below */

_background: blue; /* IE 6 */

 }
```

## In my opinion the second one is the best way!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it using this **conditional statement**

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  // Your css for IE9 and below or   
  // Perhaps importing a specific style sheet as
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9_and_below.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

you can apply **text shadow** using

```
.shadow { 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#0000FF,direction=45);
}
```

Complete [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28VS.85%29.aspx)

**gradient** can be applied as

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

The **border-image** property is not supported by IE, check: [this](http://caniuse.com/border-image)

you can make it possible using [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) for you to use a border-image in IE 6-9